# Why do I have an incompatible pointer type in C?

Tags: c, pointers

I have to write a program for my C programming that reads the strings into an typedef structure utilizing a dynamic array for it's storage, then calculate the amount of vowels and consonants in names, the vowels are ‘a’, ‘e’, ‘i’, ‘o’, ‘u’ and ‘y’. The character – (‘-‘) is neither consonant nor vowel. Then I need to update the data adding 3 years of age to each one and print out the data. Everything must be in separate functions.

- Calculate the amount of vowels and consonants in all 7 names
- Must be created using typedef structure and dynamically allocated array
- Function later on should be updated by adding 3 years to each profile and printed with the end results

The data that I need to analyze is this:

Fred Flintstone38Male

Barney Rubble36Male

Wilma Flintstone37Female

Betty Rubble36Female

Pebbles Flintstone4Female

Bam-Bam Rubble3Male

Dino Flintstone2Male

This is what I've got so far, but program keeps telling me that I have an incompatible pointer types, and I cannot figure out where is the mistake.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>


typedef struct
    {
        char name[20];
        int age[2];
        char gender[6];
    }CARTOON;

// Function Prototype Declarations
int printit(CARTOON *, FILE *);
int loaddata(CARTOON *, int, FILE *, FILE *);
void countVowel (char **pNames, int *vowel, int *consonants);
void printResults (int vowel, int consonants);

// Main
int main (void)
{
    char input[40];

    int namesIndex;
    int vowel;
    int consonants;

    CARTOON* pNames;
    FILE *tptr;
    FILE *bptr;


    FILE *fptr; //reading in the file "data.txt"
    if ((fptr=fopen("data.txt", "r"))==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening data.txt\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if((bptr=fopen("lab5dat.bin","wb"))==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error creating lab4.bin\n");
        return 2;
    }

    pNames =(char**)calloc(8,sizeof(CARTOON));
    namesIndex = 0;
    while (namesIndex < 8 && fgets(input,40,fptr))
    {
        *(pNames + namesIndex)=(char*) calloc(strlen(input)+1, sizeof(char));//pointer to first string in array namesIndex
        strcpy(*(pNames + namesIndex), input);
        namesIndex++;
    }
    *(pNames + namesIndex)=NULL;
    namesIndex = 0;
    pNames=(CARTOON*) calloc(12,sizeof(CARTOON));
    loaddata(pNames, namesIndex, tptr, bptr);
    fclose(tptr);
    fclose(bptr);
    if((bptr=fopen("lab5dat.bin","rb"))==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening lab5dat.bin\n");
        return 3;
    }
    //printit(pNames, bptr);



// Prints the items in the "lab3.dat" file.
    namesIndex=0;
    while (*(pNames + namesIndex))
    {
        printf("%s\n", *(pNames + namesIndex));
        namesIndex++;
    }

// Calls function countVowel
    countVowel (pNames, &vowel, &consonants);

//Calls function printResults
    printResults(vowel, consonants);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
} //end


int printit(CARTOON *pNames, FILE *bptr)
{
    int num;
    printf("Data from print \n\n");
    //num=fread(pNames, sizeof(CARTOON), 1, bptr);
    while (!(feof(bptr)))
    {
        num=fread(pNames, sizeof(CARTOON), 1, bptr);
        printf("%s %d %s \n",pNames->name,pNames->age,pNames->gender);
    }
    return 0;
}

int loaddata( CARTOON *pNames, int namesIndex, FILE *tptr, FILE *bptr)
{
    printf("Data from loaddata\n\n");
    while (!(feof(tptr)))
    {
        fgets((pNames + namesIndex)->name,20,tptr);
        fscanf(tptr,"%d",&pNames[namesIndex].age);
        fgets((pNames + namesIndex)->gender,18,tptr);
        fwrite((pNames + namesIndex),sizeof(CARTOON),1,bptr);
        printf("%s\n", (pNames + namesIndex)->name);
        namesIndex++;
    }
    return 0;
}


//function countVowel will count the number of vowels and consonants
void countVowel (char **pNames, int *vowel, int *consonants)
{
    int namesIndex;
    int stringIndex;

    namesIndex=0;
    stringIndex=0;
    *vowel=0;
    *consonants=0;

    while(*(pNames + namesIndex))
    {
        stringIndex=0;
        while(stringIndex<strlen(*(pNames + namesIndex)))
        {
            if (isalpha (pNames[namesIndex][stringIndex] )) //Reads only alphabets
                switch (toupper(pNames[namesIndex][stringIndex])) //makes everything capitalized.
            {    case 'A': (*vowel)++ ;break; //*vowel count gets incremented by 1 whenever a vowel is found.
                 case 'E': (*vowel)++ ;break;
                 case 'I': (*vowel)++ ;break;
                 case 'O': (*vowel)++ ;break;
                 case 'U': (*vowel)++ ;break;
                 case 'Y': (*vowel)++ ;break;
                 default: (*consonants)++;break; // Everything that is not a vowel increments consonants by 1.
            }

            stringIndex++; // goes to the next index in the string
        }

        namesIndex++; //goes to the next array index, when end of string is reached
    }

}

//Prints the result of the number of vowels and consonants
void printResults (int vowel, int consonants)
{
    printf ("\n\nThere are %d vowels and %d consonants\n\n", vowel, consonants);
}
```

Right now the error is between those two lines of codes

```
*(pNames + namesIndex)=(char*) calloc(strlen(input)+1, sizeof(char));//pointer to first string in array namesIndex
strcpy(*(pNames + namesIndex), input);
```

Comment: Umm, people don't usually want to read through a ton of code.  Telling us which line of code is in error would be helpful, no?

Comment: "program keeps telling me that I have an incompatible pointer types" -- surely it also says *where*?

Comment: Don't cast the return value of malloc, calloc or realloc. I don't care if you want to use a C++ compiler. This is C, not C++, and in C it's stupid to cast malloc, calloc or realloc.

Comment: You're trying to store a `char*` into a `CARTOON` ... that's obviously wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using pNames in two different senses in your code.

```
 CARTOON* pNames;
 ...
 pNames =(char**)calloc(8,sizeof(CARTOON));
 ...
 pNames=(CARTOON*) calloc(12,sizeof(CARTOON));
```

The type of pNames is declared appropriately for the second allocation, but not for the first.  In assigning the second allocation to the same pointer as the first without freeing, you have also leaked memory (i.e., the first allocation).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still getting warnings about lines 52 and 52 about using incompatible types. How do I fix that?

Comment: @DenysKorovets By not using incompatible types.

Answer (score 0):

```
CARTOON* pNames;
//later
pNames =(char**)calloc(8,sizeof(CARTOON));
```

Here is the incompatible pointer, you don't need the cast actually:

```
pNames = calloc(8,sizeof(CARTOON));
```

Comment: I'm just showing one, read the error information, I'm sure it has information of where the incompatible pointers are.

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring pNames as a CARTOON*, or a pointer to a CARTOON and then later storing a char**, or a pointer to a pointer to a char.  That's your mismatch.

```
pNames =(char**)calloc(8,sizeof(CARTOON));
```

In other words, you've allocated memory for a CARTOON, and then casted it to a char**.

I also noticed...

```
*(pNames + namesIndex)=(char*) calloc(strlen(input)+1, sizeof(char));
```

I'm not 100% sure about the left side, but I'd imagine after shifting and derefing the pointer, you're ending up with a char.  However, you're assigning that char (a 1-byte long piece of memory) with a pointer to a char (char*) which is not only not compatible with a char, but is 4 to 8 bytes depending on your OS.  I feel like this is asking for trouble, looks like your loop is going to be overwriting memory you're allocating.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of complexity in your code. You are trying to store the complete input string into the structure. It will not allocate data properly inside the elements of structure.

**For ex:**

You are directly copying input inside the structure. I dont think it will work as expected.

```
strcpy(*(pNames + namesIndex), input);
```

I would suggest you to parse the input and seperate name, age and gender and then store it in your structure. It will allow you to access data from structure very easily in later stages.

```
temp_name="Fred Flintstone";
temp_age=38;
temp_gender="Male";
```

After parsing it, store it into struture.

```
pNames[0].name=temp_name;
pNames[0].age=temp_age;
pNames[0].gender="Male";
```

While parsing the input to seperate the three fields, you can do the above transformation, you can calculate the vowels, increment the age.(all actions in one method).
Else you can create three modules to do everything seperatly.

```
Module 1: parse data and store it into structure. 
Module 2: find Vowels pasing the structure into it. 
Module 3: increment age passing  structure into it.
```

Also the **input name, gender** is dynamic in nature. It can hold any number of characters. I would sugest you to use your structure as dynamic as possible. Current structure will hold only 20 characters for name.

```
typedef struct
{
    char name[20]; // Allows maximun of 20 characters.
    int age[2];  // Holds two age for a person which is not a practical scenario.
    char gender[6]; //Holds maximum of 6 characters.
}CARTOON;
```

This will not suit your requirement. you have used array to store age but you are directly calling age which is not possible.

```
printf("%s %d %s \n",pNames->name,pNames->age,pNames->gender); //pNames->age[0] or pNames->age[1]
fscanf(tptr,"%d",&pNames[namesIndex].age); // &pNames[namesIndex].age[0] or &pNames[namesIndex].age[1]
```

You can try the following structure instead.

```
typedef struct
{
     char *name;
     int age;
     char *gender;
}CARTOON;
```